# StackOverFlowError Clojure change order of list

Tags: list, recursion, clojure, stack-overflow

I want to be able to take a list in clojure like

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

and change the order like this:

```
(9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

I could not find a built-in function for (inverting? Is that a good term?) turning lists back to front or whatever you wanna call the action, if there is I'd be very thankful if someone pointed that out since creating this function is not my goal it's just a step I need to pass to do what I really want to do. Anyway I wrote a function that should do it but I get this error:

```
StackOverflowError   clojure.core/seq (core.clj:133)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `reverse`?

Comment: I looked it up and yes indeed I am! This made everything much simpler, thank you! I'm pretty new to clojure and missed that one.

Comment: in terms of debugging what you have... You probably have an infinite loop, and use `loop`/`recur` for recursion

Comment: Your last statement turns the logic around. `l1` is the one you want to shrink by building up `l2` - but in your else-branch you append to `l1`

Comment: Oh my I turned things around didn't I? Thank you, it now works with the last line amended: (my-reverse (rest l1) (conj l2 (first l1))))))